# How do I reverse the "direction" the width changes on my div element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm relatively new to front end design, and so when I was creating a website I reached an issue that I am not experienced enough to properly describe, let alone solve.

Basically, I have a "banner," and has you move your mouse over it two sides are revealed. When in the middle of the banner, both text sides are revealed, and if you move left you reveal images (represented by the grey divs) relating to the right word, and vice-versa.

The issue is that the way that the text "disappears" is opposite to the movement of the mouse, breaking the illusion. I am wondering how I can make the text "switch" directions of shrinking and growing. Sorry for being bad at describing all this, the attached JSFiddle should help show what I mean. Then grey divs behave in the way I expect, just not the text.

I tried every combination of justify: left/right, right/left: 50%, without it changing anything or the correct thing. Also tried absolute positioning and the element would become invisible, even after adding a fixed width and ensuring that the element was in the viewport.

```js
let root;

$("body").ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
    var xPos = event.pageX;
    root.style.setProperty("--mouse-x", xPos + "px");
  });

  $(".container-top").on("mouseout", function(event) {
    var xPos = window.innerWidth / 2;
    root.style.setProperty("--mouse-x", xPos + "px");
  });
});

function start() {
  root = document.documentElement;
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  color: white;
}

.slider-bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 64px;
  width: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: black;
}

.container-top {
  height: 64px;
  width: 512px;
}

.container-middle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  position: relative;
}

.container-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-bottom div {
  height: 64px;
  min-width: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: black;
}

.left {
  justify-content: left;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.right {
  justify-content: right;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.text {
  background: none;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: red;
  margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="start()">
  <div class="container-top">
    <div class="slider-bar" style="left: calc(var(--mouse-x) + 36px); z-index: 2;"></div>
    <div class="container-middle" style="transform: translate(256px, 0)">
      <div class="container-bottom left" style="width: calc(var(--mouse-x) - 256px);">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>

      </div>
      <div class="container-bottom right" style="width: calc(256px - var(--mouse-x));">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-middle" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 256px;">
      <div class="container-bottom text right" style="width: calc((var(--mouse-x) - 256px) + 256px); justify: right;">
        <h2>Left Text</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="container-bottom text left" style="width: calc(256px - (var(--mouse-x) - 256px)); justify: left;">
        <h2>Right Text</h2>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.php) answer your question?

Comment: `$("body").ready(function() {` looks like it should just be `$(unction() {`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss They're equivalent.

Comment: @Barmar Yes but the latter is the current recommended form (if I had typed it correctly .... ads `$(function() {`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss True, but I think this is one of those old habits that we'll never eradicate, so good luck tilting at that windmill.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm afraid not, unless I am applying it wrong. Since the property changed by moving the mouse is 'width,' changing the transform origin doesn't change non transform (ie translate or skew) functions.